# Select distinct data from SQL Server using 2 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, distinct

I want to be able to pull back 1 row of data from a `queuedmessage` table for each email template we use. When I use group by on the `queuedmessageid` I get all records back. Ideally I want just one `queuedmessageid` back for each message template. Here is my code.

```
select distinct(messagetemplateid), QueuedMessageId 
from mail.QueuedMessage
where messagesent = 1
group by messagetemplateid, QueuedMessageId
```

I am expecting back 1 for each template we have in the database so a max of 250 rows. Instead I am getting back all the data for each `messagetemplate`.

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's an operator. It effects the *entire* dataset. Also, having a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` when you have *no* aggregation literally makes no sense. Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Assuming that `QueuedMessageId` is the primary key for table `mail.QueuedMessage` (which seems highly probable), then distinct and group by do nothing useful here as that column alone is always unique / distinct. You can try `MIN` as suggested or search for "first in group" for other similar issues / solutions

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. The answer below has solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not a function!  `SELECT DISTINCT` is a clause.  And one rarely, rarely used with `GROUP BY`.

Try an aggregation function:

```
select messagetemplateid, min(QueuedMessageId)
from mail.QueuedMessage
where messagesent = 1
group by messagetemplateid;
```

Comment: Thanks I understand this now and it works exactly the way I needed it too